# On change the text field alert and not on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is one create category button and once user click on create account and input text in text field and BLUR there should be alert that "Click save to save categories". if user click on save button alert should not come.

I am trying to use blur function but when user click on save button there is also alert for that , what is the best possible way to ignore alert on click of Save button.

```
<button type="submit" class="button" >Save</button>

<input type="text" name="category_name">

$("input[name=category_name]").change(function(){    
    alert("Click save to save categories");                                    
});
```

Comment: Do you specifically need to alert a message to the screen to tell someone something they would instinctively do? It seems bad for the UX to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var blurTimeout;

function cancelBlur(){
    clearTimeout(blurTimeout);
}

$(function(){

    $("input[name=category_name]").blur(function(){    
        blurTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            alert("Click save to save categories");                                    
        }, 200);
    });

});

</script>

<button type="submit" class="button" onclick="cancelBlur();">Save</button>
<input type="text" name="category_name" />
```

This sets a timer to show the alert message and if the submit button is clicked, it removes the timer, hence preventing the message from appearing.

Make sure to add the `onclick="cancelBlur();"` to your button

Comment: @Dayana in your code it says `$("input[name=category_name]").change(`, did you change it to `$("input[name=category_name]").blur(` ? And make sure jQuery.js is included ;)

Answer (score 1):

try that on onClick() to set a variable to true. Then, onBlur() try to trigger the alert after 1 second (or less) with setTimeout() and check for the variable to be false. If it's true, do not trigger the alert. Hope that makes sense

Comment: var flag = false;

    $('button.button').click(function() {
       var flag = true;
    });

$("input[name=category_name]").live("blur", function() {
    if(flag == false) {
        alert("Please save category first.");
    }
});

Comment: in the click event function you should get rid of the `var` part. It has already been used before.

Comment: Yes i removed that.Now First time if i click on save button its alert me..its wrong..and if first time i clicked outside of that button and after then on button and its working fine.

Comment: and I said you should delay the blur function. `blurTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ if(flag == false) { alert("Click save to save categories"); } }, 200);`